# Chat/message room and forum development using Hippo CMS/portal

Tags: content-management-system, hippocms

I am planning to use Hippo CMS for one of my site development. In this site i need to have following features-

Chat/message room: It should be possible to create different chat/message rooms and allocate users to them. Once user logs in on frontend site, he should be able to see messages posted by other members in that room. also he should be able to post own text messages there. somewhat similar to IRC

Forum: i need to build a forum where users will be able pose articles, etc.

Are these 2 features possible to develop using Hippo CMS / Hippo portal 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your 2 questions:

Building a chat room is possible. With a rich and interactive framework like Apache Wicket, in which the cms is mostly built, you can create connections to the Hippo Repository. For examples using wicket and the cms you can check out the demo project located:

http://www.onehippo.org/site-toolkit/getting+started/checkout+demo

You can build a forum pretty well. It is almost like creating a normal HST (Hippo Site Toolkit) site. You define how you want it to be represented in the repository and with some form handling you can store and retrieve the data with the hippo repository.

You can see how for example; comments are handled in our demo project which can be found via our own website.

When you need more (technical) info, please send an email to hippo-cms7-user@lists.onehippo.com. For more general info send me an email at h.keijmel@onehippo.com.

Regards and good luck,

Hans Keijmel

Comment: So does it mean that there are no pre-defined templates, etc. which i can use for rapid building of new forum? will i need to design and configure everything from basics to build complete forum?